# How can I dynamically import GitHub repository inside another GitHub repository?

Tags: git, web, github

I'm setting my website page on GitHub pages, and I do have another repository with a webpage which is independent of my personal webpage. How can I make my personal webpage's repository dynamically import the code from the other repository?

I have already searched for submodules but I think they don't import the code dynamically, plus I only want a bunch of files of the second repository, not the whole thing.

I've seen also GitHub webhooks but I don't see the way I could do it.

The key is that I don't want to be adding manually the new changes on both of the repositories, I would like to do it only in the one which is not my personal webpage and let the code flows automatically to the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple approach (no submodule or subtree required) is to combined:

- a [User Page](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user-and-organization-pages-sites) (`<username>.github.io`), which is your main site, from the master branch only of your User repo,
- some Project page (`http(s)://<username>.github.io/<projectname>`)

That way, `http(s)://<username>.github.io` does import/include `projectname` in its dedicated folder.

But that applies only to *your* project pages repos, not to *any* GitHub repo.